# Using textfield to recognize the if conditions - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

Is it possible to use the different `UITextFields` to identify the conditions to execute? For example if the user touches `UITextField *tf1` it must access one condition (using a if statement) and if the user touches `UITextField *tf2` it must access another condition. I tried using `tags` doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are definitely the right solution.  Make sure that each of your textfields has its own unique tag, and make sure you cast the sender to a control type in your action method before reading it.  I like to define constants for them to make it clear what each control is for.  For example, in the header file:

```
#define RED_TEXT_FIELD 1
#define BLUE_TEXT_FIELD 2
```

In the code:

```
-(void) onTouchTextField:(id)sender {

   UITextField *theField = (UITextField *)sender;
   if (theField.tag == RED_TEXT_FIELD) {
      ...do something...
   } 
   else if (theField.tag == BLUE_TEXT_FIELD) {
      ...do something...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UITextField` delegate methods like :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == tf1)
    {
        // Do something if tf1 is touched
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something if tf2 is touched
    }
}
```

Hope this might help you....